# How can I write in Mathematica that 2*x is an integer?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, assumptions, inequalities

I have to maximize $h/k^2$, where $h/k^2 < 0.1974$ and $k$ is an integer, and $2\cdot h$ is an integer, $h>0$, $k>0$.

How can I write this problem in Mathematica?

Comment: x being an integer implies 2x is an integer so you can just add that condition

Comment: @b3m2a1 But 2x being an integer doesn't imply that x is an integer. :-)

Comment: @BrettChampion ah is that a case they need to consider? Welp

Comment: Instead of h use h2= 2 h as variable: NMaximize[{hh/2/k^2, hh/2/k^2 < 0.1974, hh > 0, 
  k > 0, (hh | k) \[Element] Integers}, {hh, k}]

Comment: Isn't it clear there is no maximum, if `k` may be as large as we please?

Comment: Using a larger range of values for the variables will get better answers from NMaximize.  There's an infinite set of values for {h,k} for which h/k^2=0.1974, so if the bound on that is strict, there is no finite maximum, just a sequence that gets closer and closer to 0.1974.

Answer (score 6):

To find the value of $h$ for a given $k$, introduce a new variable, $n=2h$ and use `Maximize`.  As an example, for $k=5$ we can do this

```
{f, cond}={h / k^2, {0 < h, h / k^2 > 0.1974}} /. h - > n/2;
m = Maximize[{f, cond} /. k -> 5, n, Integers]

(*  {0.18, {n -> 9}}  *)
```

We can recover $h$ with `h = n/2 /. Last[m]`.  We can generate the point $(h,k,f(h,k))$ like this

```
{h, k, max} = {n/2, k, f} /. k -> 5 /. Last[m]

(*  { 9/2, 5, 9/50 }  *)
```

We can generate a table of 3D points $(h,k,f(h,k))$ and use it in a visualization like this

```
pts = Table[Block[{n, max = Maximize[{f, cond}, n, Integers]},
    {n/2 /. Last[max], k, First[max]}], {k, 2, 20}];

ContourPlot[h/k^2 == 0.1974, {h, 0, 10}, {k, 0, 10},
 Epilog -> {Red, Point[pts[[All, {1, 2}]]]}, 
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"h", "k"},
 GridLines -> {Range[10], Range[10]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The following produces an increasing sequence $(h_j/2)/k_j^2$, with $h_j,k_j$ positive integers, that converges to 0.1974 = 987/5000:

```
NestList[
 # /. {x_ :> (
     2500 Numerator[x] + 
      2961 Denominator[x]/2)/(100^2 Denominator[x])} &,
 1/8,
 n]
```

Consequently, there is no maximum. The following produces an answer because of a numerical precision issue:

```
NMaximize[{(h/2)/k^2, (h/2)/k^2 < 0.1974 && k \[Element] Integers && 
   h \[Element] Integers && h > 0 && k > 0}, {h, k}]
```

But the answer is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As Michael E@ shows, there is no maximum -- there are choices of $h$ and $k$ such that $h/k^2$ is arbitrarily close to 0.1974.

However, your question is explicitly about writing a particular constraint.  It is possible to use domain specifications, for example `Element[k,Integers]`.  Unfortunately, the list of domains doesn't include half-integers.  But we can address this by introducing a new integral variable and letting it equal $2h$.  Here's a `FindInstance` demonstrating this method:

```
FindInstance[{h/k^2 < 0.1974, Element[k, Integers], 
    2 h == m, Element[m, Integers], 
    0 < h, 0 < k}, {h, k, m}]
(* {h -> 862.5, k -> 568, m -> 1725} *)
```

(Not an impressive instance, $h/k^2 = 0.0026733{\dots}$, but it does demonstrate the method of introducing an auxiliary integral variable.)